# How to sleep a button setText?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Hey guys I am trying to make a game of matching cards. 
If two cards match user gets a point and cards stay visible, otherwise flip them (or setText("")) I did my research about swing sleep but I wasn't sure how to implement it in my code. I have tried about everything but I can't get it to work. I have this code running in main.

```
ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JButton selectedButton = (JButton)e.getSource();

            for (int row = 0; row < 6;row++){
                    for(int col = 0; col < 6; col++){
                        if (buttons[row][col] == selectedButton){
                            flipCard(row, col);
                            if(stack.empty()){
                                stack.push(row+","+col);
                            }else{
                                String word = (String)stack.pop();
                                String[] ar = word.split(",");
                                System.out.println(ar[0] + " " + ar[1]);
                                if (cardList.getCardNode(row, col).getLetter() ==
                                        cardList.getCardNode(Integer.parseInt(ar[0]),
                                        Integer.parseInt(ar[1])).getLetter()){
                                    System.out.println("equal");
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("not equal");
                                    //Compiler complains 
                                    //Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.Timer cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton
                                    Timer timer = new Timer(100 ,this);
                                    timer.setRepeats(false);
                                    timer.start();
                                    buttons[row][col].setText("");
                                    buttons[Integer.parseInt(ar[0])]
                                            [Integer.parseInt(ar[1])].setText("");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is a `taskPerformer`?  NVM - For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Also, a single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: *"//Compiler complains"* - What does it say? And do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498)?

Comment: Now I want to see a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "think" what you should be doing is something more like...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //Pop stack coordinates and set them back to ""
        //setText on button clicked to ""
        System.out.println(cardList.getCardNode(row, col).getLetter());        
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Which will, after a delay of 100 milliseconds, call the `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed` method, allowing you to reset the state of the UI...

> problem is I am inside the loop and have only access to row and col as it is clicked

Then create a `ActionListener` which take the required information and act upon it when the `actionPerformed` method is called...

```
public class FlipperHandler implements ActionListener {
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private int[] card1, card2;

    public FlipperHandler(JButton[] buttons, int[] card1, int[] card2) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
        this.card1 = card1;
        this.card2 = card2;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        buttons[card1[0]][card1[1]].setText("");
        buttons[card2[0]][card2[2]].setText("");     
    }
}
```

Then use it with the `Timer`...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new FlipperHandler(buttons, 
                                        new int[]{row, col},
                                        new int[]{Integer.parseInt(ar[0]), Integer.parseInt(ar[1])});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Comment: problem is I am inside the loop and have only access to row and col as it is clicked.

Comment: Make an `ActionListener` class, which takes the information you need in order to reset the state