# How to use JButtons like flipping cards in java

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a `JFrame` containing some `JButton`s and after clicking them they should flip like a card and show another `JPanel`.

Is there any way to create a `JButton` with flipping capability?

Comment: It depends, do you want the animation as well?  You could use a `CardLayout` to switch between different views

Comment: Conceptually similar [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498), flipping a panel from one view to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: Yest it is possible, but you will have to write your own button-alike component that will handle proper animations (step painting). There is no built-it functionality in none of standard swing components. You can try to find animated controlls on the net (I havent search for such).