# Change button image after a while

Tags: java, image, swing, timer, delay

I am developing a memory match game. When user clicks a button then icon of that button changes. And if two images(icons) are same the both buttons hide. But if not their icons are set to default.

I am facing problem that when two images are same first one is shown but when second button is clicked if icon match with previous button then I want that 2nd button icon should be visible for a while. Means I want to add delay.
Edit :Here is my code:

```
    if (count==1)
    {
        arr[0]=b;
        sscard[0]=c;
    }
    if(count==2)
    {
        arr[1]=b;
        sscard[1]=c;
        if ((arr[0]!=arr[1]) && (sscard[0]==sscard[1]))
        {
                arr[0].setVisible(false);
                arr[1].setVisible(false);
                hide+=2;
                if (hide==20)
                {
                    t.stop();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"YOU WON");
                }
                count=0;
        } 
        else
        {
            arr[0].setIcon(icon);
            arr[1].setIcon(icon);
            count=0;

        }    
    }
```

Comment: Use a (single shot - non repeating) Swing `Timer`.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498)