# What's wrong with my Java Timer method?

Tags: java

Apologies if this is lacking of context. I'll try to make it clear.

I am making this Memory type game in which some JButton subclasses have ActionListeners. When they get clicked, I check some logical criteria and if they're true I do something like

```
System.out.println("WOOO");
pause();

private static void pause(){
    paused = true;
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    paused = false;
                }
            }, 
            1500
    );

}
```

But it just keeps passing over the pause method instantaneously. It does get executed and pause gets set to false, but it doesn't halt for 1.5 secs. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"I am making this Memory type game in which some JButton"* - Then use a Swing `Timer`, it will easier and safer. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.  Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498) for example

Comment: Actually I just tried following your link and it still blazes past the timer...

Comment: There's also a runnable example at the end of the first comment, did you look at that? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses