# I am a beginner and I am trying to make a card flip game in netbeans

Tags: java, swing

On clicking an image I want another image to be displayed pause for one second and the original image to be restored and displayed againdisplayed again When I try to do it it action handler such as code given below it sets the image after sleep .I want the image to be displayed pause and the original to be displayed again how can I achieve that

```
private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    jButton16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\O.png"));  
    try {           //sleep 1 seconds 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {                   
    }

    jButton16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\118px-AMIGO.jpg"));     }
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the root cause of your issue and then have a look at [Using Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution

Comment: You could also have a look [at the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498) which basically does what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2):

You should never invoke `Thread.sleep()` inside [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
because `Thread.sleep()` will block Event Dispatch Thread and your UI will be Freeze , instead you could use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to achieve your goal

Refer below code,

```
    jButton16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\O.png"));
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jButton16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\118px-AMIGO.jpg"));
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
```

Comment: You should also never update or modify the UI from outside the context of the UI - a Swing `Timer` would be a simpler and safer solution

Answer (score 2):

- Swing is single threaded, you should never perform long running or blocking operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
- Swing is NOT thread safe, this means you should never update the UI (and anything the UI needs) outside of the context of the EDT

The simplest solution to your problem is to use a Swing `Timer`

```
private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    jButton16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\O.png"));  
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\118px-AMIGO.jpg"));     
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details