# Memory Game Action Listener Debugging

Tags: java, swing, debugging

After much time spent trying to get my actionlistener to do what I want, Ive come to a few issues debugging that Im just not comprehending.

After finding a correct pair in the game, the first correct pair works properly, disables the two selected buttons, and moves on. After this the comparisons stop working. I can't seem to find out why. After setting up System.out.print checks to see if the programming was progressing through the clicks again it was, but its not allowing another comparison to happen or button reset from the else statement.

Below I've listed my main actionlistener and my pause action listener. Thank you, and if you need more data id be happy to update.

```
  ActionListener timerPause = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            for (int i = 0; i < jToggleLength; i++) {

                jToggleButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
                tempIconThree = ((ImageIcon) 
        jToggleButtons[i].getSelectedIcon()).getDescription();

                    //flip the selected buttons back over
                if(jToggleButtons[i].isSelected()){
                       jToggleButtons[i].doClick();

                    }
                }
        }
    };

    /**
     * sets the pause timer period to 1.5 seconds
     * sets it to the actionListener Timerpause
     */

    pause = new Timer(1500, timerPause);


   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    //starts timer
    //increments click on each action
    pause.stop();
    timer.start();
    click++;

    //if jtogglelength = 0 the user has completed the game and the timer stops
    if (jToggleLength == 0) {

        timer.stop();
        click = 0;

    }

    //on first click the jtoggle button source is set to temp and the temp icon gets description
    if (click == 1) {

        temp = (JToggleButton) ae.getSource();
        tempIcon = ((ImageIcon) temp.getSelectedIcon()).getDescription();

    }
    // on click two the jtoggle button source is set to tempTwo and the tempTwo icon gets description
    if (click == 2) {

        tempTwo = (JToggleButton) ae.getSource();
        tempIconTwo = ((ImageIcon) tempTwo.getSelectedIcon()).getDescription();

        //if the button is the same button set click to zero and do nothing else
        if (temp == tempTwo) {

            click = 0;

        //if the temp icon descriptions are equivalent move forward
        }  else if (tempIcon.equals(tempIconTwo)) {

                click = 0;

                //this for loop sets tempIconThree in every loop to compare to my first two icon descriptions
                //if they match, disable that button and set the button to null
                //if the button is not null add it to an arraylist
                for (int j = 0; j < jToggleLength; j++) {

                    tempIconThree = ((ImageIcon) jToggleButtons[j].getSelectedIcon()).getDescription();

                    if (tempIcon.equals(tempIconThree) || tempTwo.equals(tempIconThree)) {

                        jToggleButtons[j].setEnabled(false);
                        jToggleButtons[j] = null;

                        if (jToggleButtons[j] != null) {

                            arrayEdit.add(jToggleButtons[j]);
                        }

                    }

                }
                //reduce the length of the array by 2
                //make a new version of the main jtogglebutton array with reduced length
                //add the non null elements from the arrayList to the array
                jToggleLength = -2;
                for (int k = 0; k < jToggleLength; k++) {

                    jToggleButtons = new JToggleButton[jToggleLength];
                    jToggleButtons[k] = arrayEdit.get(k);

                }

                click = 0;
            //if the icon descriptions did not match
            //disable all buttons, pause for 1.5 seconds, flip the 
            selected buttons back up
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < jToggleLength; i++) {

                    jToggleButtons[i].setEnabled(false);


                }

                pause.start();
                click = 0;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you deselect the previous matched buttons, otherwise it's going to match the first match, again...This is way you should separate you data/model from your view

Comment: That was actually part of my debugging at some point, Ill try it again. Thank you.

Comment: They have been deselected and the issue still exists. Thank you though, and I need to read up on separating data/model.

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly demonstrates your issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer I definitely will. I am not having one last issue! What do you need to do to make a jtimer run? I currently just want it to use 1.5 seconds. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Well, [that's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498)