# The cards do not rotate correctly in my video game made in java (swing)

Tags: java, swing

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent eventClick) {
            
            // Recovery Card from JLabel //
            JLabel labelCardClicked = (JLabel)eventClick.getSource();
            ImageIcon imageCardClicked = (ImageIcon)labelCardClicked.getIcon();
            Card clickedCard = getCardWithFileaname(imageCardClicked.getDescription());
            // FLIP //
            imageCardClicked = new ImageIcon(clickedCard.getLogo());
            imageCardClicked.setDescription(clickedCard.getId());
            labelCardClicked.setIcon(imageCardClicked);
            
            sameCardPressed(labelCardClicked, clickedCard);
            
            if(numberCardsClicked == 2) {
                Boolean status = controller.sameCard(cardsInGame);
    
                //timer.start();
                validateGameUser(status); // Problem here
                //To be continued ...
}
```

My program is the typical card game that when you click on a card, it flips over, and if you make a match, they are removed from the GUI.

Well, when you start the game and click on one card, it flips, but when you click on the second one you don't see that effect. I think it's because there's a one second timeout missing before you get to validateGameUser (status);

That's the only reason I see for it to fail me..., the first card flips and we see it, but the second one doesn't .... when I debug with "System.put.println()" I can see that the card flips, but it's not seen in the GUI as in the first card, that's why I think it reaches validateGameUser (state) very fast and you don't notice the change (since they are removed from the GUI). So I was thinking about a timer .... but I don't know how to link it to my program :/

Comment: I don't see any logic that does the flipping. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292498/swingworker-thread-sleep-or-javax-swing-timer-i-need-to-insert-a-pause/16293498#16293498) for reference